# Could you use a bread tin as a pate mould?

Tags: equipment, pate

I have bread tins and was wondering if they would work as pate molds? I'm just a little bit worried that they will rust. Also I have seen videos where youtubers line the mold with plastic to get the pate out of the mold easier, is there not a way to use something like "Cook and Spray" to stop the pate from sticking. I'm a little bit scared of the plastic melting.

[image]

Comment: Good question! I have a cookbook which stresses to never do it, but doesn't mention any reason, so I've always wondered why.

Comment: I've gotten ceramic and pyrex bread pans at thrift stores.  That might be better than shelling out for a dedicated vessel (unless you're going to be making pâté a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used a small loaf pan as a pate mold, worked just fine. I don't see any reason really not to use one as long as the size is good for what you intend.

I don't like the plastic wrap idea, I'm not interested in cooking with plastic in a high temp environment. With sous vide you know that temps aren't going to get above a certain temp but in the oven I'm not convinced that the edges of the wrap won't heat to a point where it's breaking down. Typically when I do a pate I'll use thin sliced bacon to line the pan which presents a non-stick layer as well as some flavor. More traditional is the use of caul fat which is a thin sheet of fat that surrounds the stomach if I am remembering correctly.

Comment: Mom did a terrine one year for christmas with a bacon wrap.  I think everyone was turned off by the limp, (seemingly?) under cooked bacon.  I can't remember if she used thin sliced or not.

Comment: Yes, when you use the bacon as a liner it doesn't get cooked to the degree that might typically be expected for bacon. I suppose that can be off-putting to folks who aren't accustomed to it but its quite typical for that kind of dish. The caul fat may be less off-putting as I would wager it just blends in more and isn't recognizable as a particular thing to people unfamiliar with that dish. I've never worked with it before so can't say for sure.

Comment: Is Caul fat not the fat linging of the liver, nitpick I know?

Comment: This resource says it surrounds the "stomach and other digestive organs". I'm not sure if the liver would be included in that "other digestive organs" bucket but it's quite possible that we're both right: http://culinaryarts.about.com/od/glossary/g/Caul-Fat.htm

Comment: In the country I'm from, you *lewers en netvet* which is an offal dish made from a mutton liver that is wrapped in caul fat, that is why I suspect it has something to do with the liver.

Comment: That link is somewhat interesting I wonder if certain charcuterie places in France would make a crépinettes, which is akin to an offal dish that at least in my part of Africa is considered 'Poor People' food.